# Perl XML::DOM closing tags

Tags: xml, perl, dom

I'm parsing and adding to an XML document, which has the following structure using Perl's [`XML::DOM`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::DOM) module.

```
<spectrum_query spectrum="7633.7633.2">
      <search_result>
        <search_hit hit_rank="1" peptide="MLATLAPEQR" >
          <alternative_protein protein="NP_7630153.2" />
          <modification_info>
            <mod_aminoacid_mass position="1" mass="147.0353996062"/>
            <mod_aminoacid_mass position="9" mass="129.0425935114"/>
          </modification_info>
          <search_score name="PSM score" value="6.99"/>
          <search_score name="PSM confidence" value="76.47"/>
          <search_score name="SpecEValue" value="3.6509737E-6"/>
          <search_score name="MVH" value="4.772447368593232E-21"/>
          <search_score name="theoretical mass" value="1145.5750592567304"/>
        </search_hit>
      </search_result>
    </spectrum_query>
```

I'm inserting the following XML tags within the 'search_hit' tag and after the last 'search_score' tag as follows using setAttribute() and appendChild() functions.

```
......
<search_score name="theoretical mass" value="1145.5750592567304"/>
<analysis_result analysis="peptideprophet">
<peptideprophet_result probability="0.7647" all_ntt_prob="(0,0,0)"/>
</analysis_result>
</search_hit>
```

I wish to write closed tags like as follows in the final output file using $doc -> printToFile("Dom.out.xml"). However in the output file closing tags are not written. Is there anyway to write the closing tags?
Thanks

```
<search_score name="PSM score" value="6.99"></search_score>
<peptideprophet_result probability="0.7647" all_ntt_prob="(0,0,0)"></peptideprophet_result>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the empty element syntax the module is defaulting to?

Comment: The first line of the example of desired output that you give is invalid XML (since the empty element syntax closes the search_score element before your end tag for it appears). The second line of the output is (possibly, I'm not too clear on XML white space rules) different to the original code since you have a text node containing a space as the element content (instead of nothing).

Comment: Sorry, that was due to copy/paste , corrected now.

Comment: the output file is to be parsed through some legacy regex matching scripts Thats why I need the closing tags

Comment: Fix the legacy scripts. If you aren't going to use tools that can cope with XML don't use XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

The [documentation for `XML::DOM`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::DOM) has this to say

> By default `XML::DOM` compresses all empty Element tags (style 0.) You can control which style is used for a particular Element by calling `XML::DOM::setTagCompression` with a reference to a function that takes 2 arguments. The first is the tag name of the Element, the second is the `XML::DOM::Element` that is being printed. The function should return 0, 1 or 2 to indicate which style should be used to print the empty tag.

It looks like format 1 is the one you want, and since you need *all* empty elements processed the same way, adding this to the top of your program should make the necessary changes

```
XML::DOM::setTagCompression ( sub { 1 } );
```

---

In XML, an *empty* element like

```
<tag></tag>
```

can also be written as

```
<tag/>
```

Because it is clearer and more concise, that is what `XML::DOM` has chosen to to in this case. Your XML data is fine

Comment: Yes, you're right and I know about the empty tags, however the output file is to be parsed through some legacy regex matching scripts Thats why I need the closing tags